# How to access the dynamically created HTML control values in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have created few HTML controls dynamically on Page load.
My Code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder
  Dim i as Integer = 0
  sb.Append("<table class ='tabledata' id='tblContent'>")
    For Each item As myObject In myList
        i += 1
        sb.Append("<tr><td>")            
        sb.Append("<textarea runat='server' id=txt_comments" & i & " 
                    name='txt_comments' rows='5' cols='60'></textarea></td>")          
        sb.Append("</tr>")
     Next        
    sb.Append("</table>")
    myDiv.InnerHtml = sb.ToString 

 End Sub
```

From the above code,
I am creating `<textarea>` HTML control dynamically on Page load by using stringbuilder and finally assiging this string to my div which is present in .aspx page

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">
```

I am able to view my dynamically created controls on Page load.

Now I want to access the values from these textboxes in a button click event(Save).

How do i do that?
Any Help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Request.Form("id_of_textarea") ?

Comment: Yes, it is throwing null reference error

Comment: Request.Form doesn't normally throw null reference, can you show us how you use it?

Comment: Request.Form("txt_comments1").ToString()

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like? Are all your textarea in the <form> that is submitted?

Comment: Yes, its in the <form>

Comment: You don't wrap the id value of the dynamically generated textarea with quotes.

Comment: @N0Alias , nope it dint work either.

Answer (score 0):

You named all your textarea as txt_comments, you'll see the data in Request.Form("txt_comments"). Add the I in the name, then you can access the data with Request.Form("txt_comments" & i)

```
    sb.Append("<textarea runat='server' id=txt_comments" & i & " 
                name='txt_comments" & i & "' rows='5' cols='60'></textarea></td>")
```

Since this is generated html, you don't need the attribute runat='server'.

---

Here is my test code. Since I don't know how you initialize myList, I just loop from 0 to 10.

html

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="myDiv" runat="server">

    </div>
        <asp:button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    sb.Append("<table class ='tabledata' id='tblContent'>")
    For i = 0 To 10
        sb.Append("<tr><td>")
        sb.Append("<textarea runat='server' id=txt_comments" & i & " 
                name='txt_comments" & i & "' rows='5' cols='60'></textarea></td>")
        sb.Append("</tr>")
    Next
    sb.Append("</table>")
    myDiv.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
End Sub

Protected Sub btnTest_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    For i = 0 To 10
        Response.Write("[" & Request.Form("txt_comments" & i) & "]")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Still no luck. I removed runat='server' and calling Request.Form("txt_comments"&i).

Comment: Did you also add the "i" in the name attribute of the textarea?

Comment: I did both..my adding i and with out i

Comment: @Santosh adding the i in the name works well for me. What are all the keys in the Request.Form dictionary?